# render to response to several textboxes in django

Tags: django, forms

Several hours later and I still haven't figured out how to do/think in this case, which I thought in the beginning would be the easiest task..

Got an html template, with seven textboxes, one for each day. The name of the textboxes is the name of the day. I write in text in them, and press submit.

Django gets it, and put everything in an database. Everything is fine.

When I then load the template again, I want the textboxes to be filled with the data from the database. But I dont know how, and I need help!

The first I did was to make a query and do a render_to_response, but then I got every field to be rendered seven times since it render everything in the query, on every textbox.

If I only have one textbox in my html template, the render_to_response works fine. But when I then change any data in the template and press submit, all textboxes have the same name, and because of that django cant separate all seven days.

```
{% for activity in activity_data %}     
        Activity  <input type="text" class="textbox" value="{{activity.excercise}}" name="monday" size="12" id="inputField1">  <p>&nbsp;</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I dont know how clear this is, if not let me know and I will try to explain more. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Do you use a django ModelForm? if yes specify an instance parameter

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but you can do this using [`{%cycle%}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) tag for iterating over day names.

```
{% for activity in activity_data %}     

 {% cycle 'monday' 'tuesday' 'wednesday' 'thursday' 'friday' 'saturday' 'sunday' as day  silent %}
  Activity  <input type="text" class="textbox" value="{{activity.excercise}}" 
                name="{{day}}" size="12" id="inputField1">  <p>&nbsp;</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Better way is that, value for `name` comes from `activity` object so that you don't have to manipulate the for loop, and you can do something `name="{{activity.day}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I solved it as your recommendation to populate the name from db with ID instead of real names of the days. Works great.